# NHibernate equivalent of SQL IsNull(column, 'defaultValue')

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover, isnull

How can I use NHibernate (preferably QueryOver syntax) to get the following SQL

```
SELECT this_.Name as_, count(IsNull(this_.Name , 'UNKNOWN') ) as NameCount
FROM...
```

Answer (score 3):

IsNull is not supported in NHibernates sql dialects, but Coalesce is, and is the same thing for two parameters.

You can do

```
Projections.SqlFunction("Coalesce", NHibernateUtil.String,
    Projections.Property("Name"), Projections.Constant("UNKNOWN"))
```

to get a projection that does the equivalent of IsNull().

Comment: There is also `Projections.Conditional`

Answer (score -2):

In ICriteria there is `NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.IsNull(PropertyName)` I think you can use it in QueryOver also -

```
var qOver = QueryOver.Of<MyEntity>(() => meEntity);

qOver = qOver.Where(Restrictions.IsNull(PropertyName));
```

Comment: The particulate requirement I have is to use a default value if the specified value is null (using 'UNKNOWN' as the default in my example)